# How to get postcode of a county through google api

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, autocomplete, google-api

I am trying to create an autocomplete text field which should only provide the postal code in dropdown. Here is the documentation which I have followed:
[google place autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

How do i get only and all the postcodes of UK over there.

```js
 src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"

src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your_api_key&libraries=places&sensor=false&callback=initialize"


function initialize() {
    $('#adv_postcode').each(function () {
        initialize2(this);
    });
}
function initialize2(elementID) {
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'uk'
        }
    };
    var autocomplete_element = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(elementID, options);
    autocomplete_element.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        elementID.value = fillInAddress(autocomplete_element);
    });
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" name="adv_postcode" id="adv_postcode" class="addressfields"/>
```

Any help highly appreciated

Comment: Kindly rearrange your code and explain the problem properly.

Comment: I have mentioned above where is the problem, the locations are coming in autocomplete instead of postcodes

Comment: you want autocomplete to show you all the uk postal codes as predictions? why don't you just fill it yourself in a dropdown? autocomplete is not going to show you only postal codes in the predictions

Comment: its impossible to fill the data because its a vast amount of data so need a autocomplete

Comment: you could just pass the postal code to autocomplete and it will find the location, but autocomplete won't result in a list of uk postal codes, it does not work like that

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the best option that you have is setting `types` parameter of [autocomplete options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions) to `(regions)`. According to the documentation

> The **(regions)** type collection instructs the Places service to return any result matching the following types:
>
> - locality
> - sublocality
> - postal_code
> - country
> - administrative_area_level_1
> - administrative_area_level_2

source: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3

Not ideal, but you will get only regions in the list of suggestions. So your code should be

```
var options = {
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'uk'
    },
    types: ['(regions)']
};
var autocomplete_element = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(elementID, options);
autocomplete_element.addListener('place_changed', function () {
    elementID.value = fillInAddress(autocomplete_element);
});
```

Also, note that there is a feature request in Google issue tracker to make `types` parameter more flexible:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820774

Feel free to star this feature request to express your interest and subscribe to notifications.